# Dash - Compile error when iterating through page_registry.values()

Tags: python, for-loop, plotly-dash

I am working through creating a multi page app and using the Dash documentation to figure it out. I am stuck on the part where we create page links by iterating through dash.page_registry.values().

This code works:

```
dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink(f"{page['name']}", href=page["relative_path"]))
        for page in dash.page_registry.values()
```

but this code does not:

```
for page in dash.page_registry.values():
        dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink(f"{page['name']}", href=page["relative_path"]))
```

I don't understand why I can't cycle through using a normal for loop.

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  What happens?  Is your first line part of an assignment, like `lst = [doc.NavItem ... registry.values()]`?  You can't have a comprehension like that stand alone.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly it. First line was adding it too .Nav so I guess you can’t do this. Follow up question though - if you have to do if with the for on the back end, how do you add elements afterwards?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  If you need to keep the `dbc.NavItem`s for later, then store them in a list using `xxx.append(...)`.